# Laravel Different Route Same Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an API for user and admin.

Got stuck at edit user profile routing.

on admin route i use `Route::resource('user', 'UserController')`

on user route i use `Route::get('profile', 'UserController@show')`

At the show method Laravel default has

```
public function show($id)
{

}
```

the different between them is on admin I can use `/id` but on user i check their token from middleware and merge the request to get their `user_id` so there is no need for the API to use `profile/{id}`.

The question is how can I use the same method but there is an argument to fill and the route still `/profile`?

---

One of my solution is :

```
public function show($id){
    if ($request->has('user_id')):
        $id = $request->query('user_id');
    endif;
}
```

It working but when i read the code, it's really redundant always checking it and replace the id.

Comment: I would totally use a different method for the profile. UserController@showProfile, for example.

Comment: yeah, that's one of solution. But it totally same for the function. the difference only about the id. thanks

Comment: Then make showProfile to get the id and call show with that id.

Comment: Will consider this approach. I will look at it more because there are update, and create too.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just place the request object as a parameter in your controller and get the input from the request object when you use your user route.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. If you don't mind, can you give me an example? Thanks